# Getting crash when click interactive notification body in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, remote-notifications

I have implemented interactive notification into app. Into interactive notification have two action buttons 'Ok' and 'Cancel'.

I have implemented a code on click of particular button. But when I click interactive notification body and not on action button that time app gets opened but after that it's crashed.

How to handle this issue? I have added code for remote notification's delegate method which is `'didReceiveRemoteNotification'`. Is this method is necessary for interactive notification?

Please anyone clarify my two questions.

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to disable 'user interaction' of interactive notification body?

Comment: But @Rohan, I am using a delegate method 'handleActionWithIdentifier' for interactive notification handle.